# How to remove Activity from IntentService

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I use WakefulBroadcastReceiver with a IntentService. My app sends and receive a data from http. I added a condition in the IntentService, when a connection is a timeout then is new activity with loading gif. At this point the new connection is established. When the connection is established, the activity is to disappear. I want call a method finish(), which close an activity and will return to a previously activity but I can't.

I try close an last activity using below code:

```
public void close() {

    this.finish();

}
```

It's not works.

Comment: post the code from the new `Activity` that shows the GIF.

Comment: OK, thanks! I resolved my problem using other solutions. I created new activity and in the created runnable which check if gobal variable is true. If is the variable is true, then my activity is closed. This runnable has one seconds period.

Comment: Great that you were able to solve your problem. Please answer your own question and accept your answer. This will remove the question from the "unanswered questions" list and maybe help someone else!